# Validation in Slide Outs (desktop)

Tags: validation, filter, sidebar

I have slide out with a bunch of filters.(sorry, because of private info I can't publish them) I can apply 1, 2 or 5 filters by clicking "Apply Filters".

[image]

By clicking on filter I can get to its settings (another slide out). To apply changes I should back and to click "Apply Filters". Changed filters have indication that show user that they are ready to apply. Cause of technical restrictions I can't put "Apply button" right on specific filter slide out.

[image]

**The question is**
should I allow user back to filters and disable "Apply Filters" button and additionally to show red indicator etc? Or should i disable yellow navigation bar "Filter List" (img 2) and don't allow user to back? so, when he open filters slide-out again he see this invalid filter slide out, not all list of filters (img 1)

Answer (score 1):

> should i disable yellow navigation bar "Filter List" (img 2) and don't allow user to back? so, when he open filters slide-out again he see this invalid filter slide out, not all list of filters

No definitely not, that is not a good user experience. when user slides for filters he should see all the filters not where he left previously while he was in this screen.(In your case)

Also don't disable back button, that is not a good practice in apps as back buttons are primarily for navigation purpose i.e to navigate between screens. even though your current screen is in invalid state you should not throw that upon back button. you need to handle this in a different way probably.

My solution for your problem would be like this:

1. **User selects any no. of filters from the filters screen.**

   [image]
2. **Once he selects any filter if that filter is having extra data's to
   filter again you show the corresponding filter screen.**

   [image]

   as you can see here there is new button I have added to save all your changes corresponding to your current filter. once you click this button it validates data and if correct it applies this filter and takes user back to filters screen with this filter applied.
3. **In case user enters invalid data then save changes button will be
   disabled. but back button will be enable all the time so that user
   can seamlessly navigate between screens.**

   [image]

Hence if invalid data then filter wont be applied at all or it can be applied with correct data which is associated currently with that filter. hope this helps :)

> should I allow user back to filters and disable "Apply Filters" button and additionally to show red indicator etc?

Yes you can show filters marked in red if those are in invalid state. it will be more intuitive and makes user correct his mistakes and gets him want he wanted out of filtered data. **Note:** make sure you do this in case you don't consider applying filter(s) even if any one of the field is invalid but rest are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should allow the user to go back, but make sure that the user is notified that their filter is wrong, on both screens. In the case that user selects to go back means that they didn't want to set the filter or did not know how to set the filter. Both reasons might cause frustration to the user if they cannot go back.

Disabling the "Apply Filters" seems like a valid behavior from the system. Notify the user about the reasons why they cannot set the filters in a very clear way and give them the option to go back to the main screen. If I were you, I would highlight the box's border by making it red or another design solution. You could also give them suggestions on how they can make the filter work.

This could be useful for you as a checklist: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/slips/